# Interoperability of openssl smime, rsautl & dgst

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, sha256

How do

```
$ openssl smime -sign -in test -text -out mail.msg -signer mycert.pem -inkey key.key
```

and

```
$ openssl rsautl -sign -inkey key.key -out test.sgn -in test
```

and

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -sign key.key -out test.sgn test
```

differ from each other concerning the digital [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature#/media/File:Digital_Signature_diagram.svg) of `test`?

Shouldn't they be interoperable to each other?: [ encrypt( SHA256( "Text" ) ) ]

I assume that it should be possible to verify with `$openssl dgst -verify...` a signature, which was created with one of the two other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between rsautl and dgst is explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951559/difference-between-openssl-rsautl-and-dgst

Regarding smime, it's saving result in email friendly format, the one which can be appended to email messages.

So all these 3 commands are not inter-operable because each command does something else.